# An Example of the Chi-Square Test

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Here is another problem dealing with the Chi-Square Test. I am hoping that somebody can confirm that I did it correctly or tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks,
Bob
Problem:
An urn contains $6$ red marbles and $3$ white ones. Two marbles are
selected at random from the urn, their colors are noted and then the
marbles are replaced in the urn. This process is performed a total
of $120$ times, and the result are given below. (a) Determine the
expected frequencies. (b) Determinate at a level of significance of $0.05$ whether
the results obtained are consistent with those expected.
There were $6$ times when $0$ red balls and $2$ white balls were drawn.
There were $53$ times when $1$ red ball and $1$ white ball were drawn.
There were $61$ times when $2$ red balls and $0$ white balls were drawn.
Answer: (a)
Let $p_{r2}$ be the probability that we draw two red balls.
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{r2} &=& \frac{6}{9} \Big( \frac{5}{8} \Big)  = \frac{30}{72} \\
p_{r2} &=&  \frac{5}{12} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence the expected number of times we draw two red balls
is $120(\frac{5}{12})$ or $50$. Let $p_{w2}$ be the probability that we draw two white balls.
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{w2} &=& \frac{3}{9} \Big( \frac{2}{8} \Big)  = \frac{6}{72} \\
p_{w2} &=&  \frac{1}{12} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence the expected number of times we draw two white balls
is $120(\frac{1}{12})$ or $10$. Let $p_{rw}$ be the probability that we draw one white ball and one red ball
in either order.
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{rw} &=&
 \frac{6}{9} \Big( \frac{3}{8} \Big) + \frac{3}{9} \Big( \frac{6}{8} \Big) \\
p_{rw} &=& \frac{18 + 18}{72} = \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence the expected number of times we draw one white ball and one red ball is $120(\frac{1}{2})$ or $60$.
(b)
I am now going to apply the Chi-Square Test to determine how good of a fit we have.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\chi^2 &=& \frac{(61-50)^2}{50} + \frac{(53-60)^2}{60} + \frac{(6-10)^2}{10} \\
\chi^2 &=& \frac{121}{50} + \frac{49}{60} + \frac{16}{10} \\
\chi^2 &=& 4.8366667 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
From a table we find that with two degrees of freedom at the 0.95 confidence level
$\chi^2_{0.95} = 5.99$. Therefore we cannot accept the hypothesis that the above
procedure was not used. We also cannot accept the hypothesis that it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(a)$, yes, your reasoning is correct.

For $(b)$, you set up your hypotheses the wrong way around. With $\chi^2$ test, we set our null hypothesis to be that our results are consistent with the expected results. Furthermore, in statistics, we never talk about accepting the null hypothesis; only whether we reject or fail to reject it.

Let $$H_0 : p_{r2}=\frac{5}{12}, p_{w2}=\frac{1}{12}, p_{rw}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$H_a :\text{ at least one of these probabilities does not hold}$$

```
> observed <- c(61,6,53)
> expected <- c(5/12,1/12,1/2)
> chisq.test(x=observed,p=expected)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  observed
X-squared = 4.8367, df = 2, p-value = 0.08907
```

Since $0.05\lt0.08907$ we **fail to reject** the null hypothesis. We do not have significant evidence to conclude that the results are inconsistent with the expectations.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your answer. 1) You are telling me that the null hypothesis is the data is consistent with the method. 2) You are telling me that in this case we fail to reject the idea it was done with the correct method. Do I have these two points right?

Comment: Yes and yes, you got that right!